# flip paste command output

Tags: linux, shell, aix

I am on AIX

file2:

```
2cat
2bat
```

my command:

```
sed command  | paste -d, - file2
```

outputs:

```
1cat,2cat
1bat,2bat
```

Output I want :

```
2cat,1cat
2bat,1bat
```

will it be possible without using temporary file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste -d, file2 -

worked for me as PSkocik suggested .